# Picking specific array element

Tags: array

I have just started reading about `"$@"` and `"$*"`, I wanted to know if I can specifically point to an element in the `"$@"` array. Like without using any loop, I want to be able to pick element number 3 from `"$@"`. Is there a way of doing this like `"$1+@"` or something like this? I already know about `"${1}"` but want to know specifically about `"$@"` and `"$*"`. I tried searching for it but did not find anything related to this.

Comment: `array=(apple banana orange); printf "%s\n" "${array[1]}"`

Comment: @jasonwryan Thanks, it worked, doesn't any syntax something specifically like `"$1+@"` or `"$@+1"` exist? I think I saw it somewhere, but am not sure because it has been a lot of time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is said that the positional parameters are not an array.
And the way that exists to set them is via `set`. No other array needs that.

```
$ set -- one two t33 f44
$ printf '%s\n' "$@"
one
two
t33
f44
```

But at least in bash (and ksh and zsh), they could be selected just as easy:

```
$ set -- one two t33 f44
$ echo "${@:2:1}"
two
$ echo "${@:2:2}"
two t33
```

Comment: If echo `echo ${@:2:1}` gives the output `two`. So does this mean that `one two t33 f44` are set at the indexes `1` `2` `3` `4` respectively instead of usual format `0` `1` `2` `3` considered in arrays?

Comment: And also, why does `echo ${@:0:1}` gives the output similar to `echo $0` i.e the current shell name?

Comment: Yes!. That's the usual numbering of positional parameters as $0 is (most of the time) the name of the running script/program. Just do an `echo $0` to see it. @GypsyCosmonaut

Comment: Well, as the zero index is the name of the executing script/shell, it must be what should be printed by asking for it with `echo ${@:0:1}`. Doesn't it? @GypsyCosmonaut

Comment: `${parameter:offset:length}` is substring expansion in general, but for `@` it is treated differently: `${@:offset:length}`you get `length` positional parameters beginning at `offset`.

Comment: This `set -- one two t33 f44; echo "${@:2:2}"` prints the exact same values as this other does `arr=(one two t33 f44); echo "${arr[@]:1:2}"`. I really fail to see any important difference between the two (except the index numbering). @Nick

Comment: I was quoting from the bash man page, but you are right: there is no difference for non-negative offsets. The "different treatment" arises only when the offset is negative (this is untested though, so I may have misunderstood).

Comment: In bash/ksh/zsh, the negative numbers work the same. The last element is -1, the rest follows that. For example: `zsh -c 'set -- one two t33 f44; echo "${@: -3:2}"'` will print `f44 f55`. The same will be printed with this: `ksh -c 'arr=(zero one two t33 f44 f55); echo "${arr[@]: -3:2}"'` Just mind the required space before the negative number and observe that I added a `zero` element to the second array (which doesn't change the result if omited). It still seems quite similar to me (in the three shells tested). @Nick

Comment: I reread the manpage and I did indeed misunderstand: the difference is between ${param:offset:length} where param is anything *but* `@` or `arr[@]`, in which case negative offsets count *characters* from the end of the string; vs the two cases `@` and `arr[@]` where negative offsets count *elements* from the end (positional params in the first case, elements of the array in the second). So yes, you are right: these last two give the same results.

Answer (score 1):

`$@` is not an array: it's just a list of the arguments. In bash, you can create an array, initialize it with the values from `$@` and then use indexing:

```
declare -a foo=($@)

echo ${foo[2]}
```

The array indices start from 0, so the above prints the third argument to the script.

Answer (score 0):

Essentially, you can't. The thing is that `$*` and `$@` are not *arrays*; they are simple *variables*. Thus, it isn't possible to index them.

Their values are just strings, defined in slightly different ways. `$1`, `$2`, etc. give you access to the individual components.

Comment: I believe that you should take a look to my answer. There is an easy way of using indexes to read elements of the positional parameters (at least on some shells)

Comment: My answer does not conflict with that. I was correcting the assumption in the question that the parameters are arrays, that's all.